# What is the role played by the `type` column in Doctrine class table inheritance?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, polymorphic-associations

Using Symfony 4 / Doctrine 2.6. I have two entities Post and Comment. I want both to be taggable. So I create an entity Tag. I use Doctrine's [class table inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) to create the relationship:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TagRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"post" = "PostTag", "comment" = "CommentTag"})
 */
abstract class Tag
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    // Getters and setters...
}

/** @ORM\Entity */
class PostTag extends Tag
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Post", inversedBy="tags")
     */
    private $post;

    public function getPost(): ?Post
    {
        return $this->post;
    }
}

/** @ORM\Entity */
class CommentTag extends Tag
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Comment", inversedBy="comments")
     */
    private $comment;

    public function getComment(): ?Comment
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }
}
```

This creates 3 tables: `tag`, `post_tag`, and `comment_tag`. The `post_tag` table structure looks like this:

```
id | post_id
```

The `tag` table structure looks like this:

```
id | title | type
```

How are e.g. posts and tags associated? If I want to associate post `13` with tag `test`, would the result be this:

**`post_tag` table:**

```
id | post_id
------------
1  | 13
```

**`tag` table:**

```
id | title | type
-----------------
1  | test  | post
```

?

If so, then what if I want to associate the same tag (`test`) with a comment. Would the `tag` table then look like this?

```
id | title | type
--------------------
1  | test  | post
2  | test  | comment
```

That seems a bit redundant. The same entity (the `test` tag) is then represented by 2 rows in the `tag` table. Am I getting this wrong?

Comment: In my opinion, since they refer to different types of entities, it's good to have them as separate tags. If you now want to rename a tag for posts but not for comments, you can. You can also show lists of available tags for a specific entity type.  I've actually never seen the feature of tagging comments before. In the end, it depends on the tags relationship to each other and what you use them for etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: inheritance is the wrong tool. A tag is a tag is a tag. Inheritance is *inherently* provided by using multiple associations (many-to-many).

Your inheritance essentially says: There are two distinct types of tags, that are essentially different. One tag, that can be applied to posts, and one tag, that can be applied to comments, and those aren't the same tags, but different tags.

Since both kinds of tags are stored in the same table, there must be *some* mechanism on how to discriminate one from the other. That's what the type column is for. (So, this is essentially the answer to your main question, afaict)

So essentially, if you want to tag comments and blog (posts) alike, these are the more common options:

1. Tags: (tag_id, tag_name, whatever), Comment_tags: (tag_id, comment_id), Blog_tags: (tag_id, blog_id) ... *(I assume, this is what you want/need)*
2. Tags: *same*, Tagassignments: (tag_id, object_type, object_id) ... *(inconvenient in Doctrine, and overall unfavorable¹)*

You chose a different approach: Tags: (tag_id, tag_name, object_type), Tagassignments: (tag_id, object_id) (<-- object type is implicitly given by tagid, but since you're using relations, Tagassignments is split up into blog_tags and comment_tags)

However, as Magnus Eriksson correctly commented, this might make sense. I have my doubts. I assume, that either option 1 or option 2 are much more common and convenient. And you should drop the inheritance on the Tag and instead add inheritance on the association (if needed, you'd need to make it an extra Entity to make it work), but rather advise on chosing option 1 because it's waaay easier to implement with doctrine and it's annotations. (although you'd need to add one get{Object}s() for each different object type that is supposed to be taggable.)

¹as Magnus correctly comments below (and co-commented by me): You lose most advantages databases provide, mainly performance, clarity and consistency. I would generally advise against this approach.

Comment: Personally, I really dislike the `object_id`-version since you have one column that refers to different tables. You also won't be able to set `object_id` as a foreign key.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I completely agree. It's almost like a key-value store. You lose all the features that databases provide, only to have "one table" where it is all stored (and that table is more inefficient and larger than the single tables com ... uncombined ^^)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I am used to your 2nd option, since this is how Laravel Eloquent implements polymorphic relationships. I will try the first option. Just to be clear, do you mean that for option 1 I would need to extend my `Post` and `Comment` entities (instead of what I'm doing now, which is extending my `Tag` entity)?

Comment: Ah no. If I understand you right, for option 1 no inheritance is needed at all. I just create 2 new entities, `Comment_tags` and `Post_tags`, and use normal relationships to define their columns.

Comment: no, for option 1 you only need to define the associations, unless you want the associations to bear extra properties apart from {object}_id and tagid.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of posterity, this is the approach I took to implement @Jakumi's answer:

1. Scrap the existing tables.
2. Create a `Tag` entity with the symfony console, with the following fields:

   a) `post` (type: relation; many-to-many)

   b) `comment` (type: relation; many-to-many)

   c) `title` (type: string)
3. Make & run migrations.

This automatically created the tables `tag_post` and `tag_comment`.

Comment: since it's many-to-many (so, every tag has many posts and many comments) it's common to use the plural. but that's just a detail ;o)